# Garbled text on startup (Server 16.04)

Tags: boot, grub2, 16.04, startup, screen-corruption

I'm having an issue with my Ubuntu Server 16.04 installation. I have it running on a Zotac Z-Box CI23 Nano. It installed fine, but on its first boot all I had was a blank screen. I edited `/etc/default/grub` and changed `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"`

This let me see the startup, but the text is all garbled white blocks:

[image: example]

I first thought it might be a bad cable, so I switched cables with no change. I changed monitors with no effect. I switched to a TV using HDMI with no effect.

Any ideas would appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally got this figured out. At first I thought it was bad hardware so I RMA'd the machine. The same exact thing was happening on the replacement. So I spent a few hours fiddling with grub settings. This is what ended up working for this machine:

in `/etc/default/grub`:

Comment out `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet"` entirely.
Uncomment `GRUB_TERMINAL=console`

Uncomment `GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` I set it to `GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x800` because that's the monitor I'm using's default.

Save it then `sudo update-grub` and reboot and it is showing as expected. Only the combination of those three changes seem to make it work for me, but YMMV.

Comment: Are you saying the problem is solved? If so can the bounty be removed?

Comment: Yes it can, I couldn't figure out how to remove it.

Comment: @boredemt It can't be removed. You can't award it to yourself AFAIK. But, after the bounty period ends, you *might* get half of it back, if your answer is the most-upvoted one (sorry, don't have much info on that).